# Axios function is running twice for some reason in react

Tags: reactjs

Im not sure why but it seems that my axios function is running twice is there any way I could circumvent this? I have a couple useState methods above but I am still confused why it is basically running everything twice

here is the code that is running twice in react

```
function App() {
  let num = [];
  num[0] = 0;

  if (localStorage.getItem("winstreak") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("winstreak", JSON.stringify(num));
  } else {
  }

  let winstreak = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("winstreak"));
  let array = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("winstreak"));
  let streaks = winstreak.reduce(
    function (res, n) {
      if (n) res[res.length - 1]++;
      else res.push(0);
      return res;
    },
    [1]
  );

  let streak = Math.max.apply(Math, streaks);
  var current = localStorage.getItem("gamesplayed", 0);
  var correct = localStorage.getItem("correctgames", 0);
  localStorage.getItem("winstreak", winstreak);

  const [victory, setVictory] = useState("");
  const [seconds, setseconds] = useState();
  const [minutes, setminutes] = useState();
  const [hours, sethours] = useState("");
  const [useHint, setHint] = useState(false);
  const [gamestatus, setGameStatus] = useState(false);
  const [Attempts, SetAttempts] = useState(0);
  const [divnum, setDiv] = useState(1);
  const [complete, setComplete] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [buttonpopup, setbuttonpopup] = useState(false);
  const [tweets, setTweet] = useState();
  const [sharebut, setSharebut] = useState(false);
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState();
  const [answer2, setAnswer2] = useState();

  getTweet();
  function getTweet() {
    axios
      .get("https://tweetleserver.herokuapp.com/")
      .then((res) => {
        setTweet(res.data.data.id);
        setAnswer(res.data.includes.users[0].name);
        setAnswer2(res.data.includes.users[0].username);
        console.log("test");
        return;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      });
  }
}
```

I am calling this function only once but I am still confused as to why it could be doing this

Comment: `I am calling this function only once` Can you show us where you call it?

Comment: I just edited the post I am callling it right before I define the function im not sure if that should matter though because the function still seems to work

Comment: If you are using React 18 strict mode, on development the component will mount-unmount-remount, which means it is mounted twice: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state . Just a guess as it is a bit difficult to tell from your code.

Comment: would it be fine to post my entire code it is pretty long I wasnt sure if I could or not. I made sure to remove the strict mode and when I deploy this site on something like netlify the issue seems to still happen

Comment: It looks like you're calling the function in the body of the component... that will cause you to call this function every time the component renders. If it's only getting called twice, consider yourself lucky, since this usually causes an infinite loop! You need to move this code into a `useEffect` to limit when it's called.

Comment: @NicholasTower  wow dude i've been trying to fix this for a couple days and that worked instantly thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move the getTweet() inside useEffect will solve the infinit loop (whether you have it) because it's not nice practice if you call it directly in the body of the functional component.
Also i would prefer to have one setState , so one state instead of having multi states .
I mean instead of :

```
setTweet(res.data.data.id);
setAnswer(res.data.includes.users[0].name);
setAnswer2(res.data.includes.users[0].username);
```

you can write this :

```
setSomeState(prevState => ({
...prevState,
tweet: res.data.data.id
answer: res.data.includes.users[0].name,
answer2: res.data.includes.users[0].username
}));
```

and the state will be :

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({
 tweet: "",
answer: "",
answer2: ""
});
```